# Webpack - Cache busting using auto-versioning with hash values

Tags: javascript, caching, hash, webpack, versioning

I've been trying for weeks to get cache busting to work with Webpack, pouring through [posts](https://medium.com/@okonetchnikov/long-term-caching-of-static-assets-with-webpack-1ecb139adb95#.vfxeqhcyw), [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/long-term-caching.html), and the documentation of each added plugin, but I can't figure out how to get it right. I want to cache-bust using hashes, and not using query parameters. This is my current configuration -- everything commented w/ `*` means that it was included purely for the sake of cache-busting:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin'); // *
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); // *
var WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash'); // *


var basePlugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    __PRODUCTION__: true,
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
  }),
];

var usedPlugins = [
  new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compressor: {
      warnings: false,
    },
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ // *
    names: "manifest" // *
  }), // *
  new AssetsPlugin(), // *
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin(), // *
  new WebpackMd5Hash(), // *
];


/* Config */
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: [path.join(__dirname, '/lib/main')],
  },
  eslint: {
    configFile: 'lib/.eslintrc',
  },
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
    alias: {
      ... // a bunch of aliases
    },
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/pub/'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js', // *
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js', // *
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].js.map',
    publicPath: '/pub/',
  },
  plugins: usedPlugins,
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      ... // some preloaders
    ],
    loaders: [
      ... // some loaders
    ],
  },
};
```

When I build this in production, under `prodBuild/pub` folder, I get 3 files:

- `main.[someHashHereButWithoutTheBrackets].js`
- `manifest.[someOtherHashHereAndAlsoWithoutTheBrackets].js`
- `index.html`

The `index.html` under `pub` is generated *even though* there's an `index.html` under `prodBuild`, which is the html page that is served to the client.

So the file structure looks something like this:

```
/prodBuild
    /pub
        main.[someHashHereButWithoutTheBrackets].js
        manifest.[someOtherHashHereAndAlsoWithoutTheBrackets].js
        index.html // call this indexB
    /anotherFolder1
    ...
    /anotherFolderK
    index.html // call this indexA
```

Again, without any of this attempt at cache-busting, `indexA` is what is served to the client. In it there a number of script tags such as:

```
<script src="pub/main.js></script> // in indexA
```

However, in `indexB`, not only are there other missing html tags, but I only get two script tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Broken Webpack App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/pub/manifest.[someOtherHashHereAndAlsoWithoutTheBrackets].js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/pub/main.[someHashHereButWithoutTheBrackets].js"></script></body>
</html>
```

So while it appears the hashing is working (and that is what I want), there are still several issues:

- The hashing does not appear in the correct `index.html` file, i.e. it shows up in `indexB`, not `indexA`.
- `indexB` contains only two of the scripts that are in `indexA`.
- In `indexB`, there are many html tags that are missing, but are present in `indexA`.

To recap, what I need is cache-busting, using the type of hashing I have described above. I am not at all versed in webpack, but what I would presume to be the end result is `indexA` to be exactly the same, except with hashes on the file name.

What needs to be done to get cache-busting properly working?

---

**UPDATE:**
I do not mean a hashtag as Thomas has referenced. I mean a hash value, as I've described in my post.

Comment: Webpack hashing is not intuitive. The hash is computed in the middle of the compilation steps, meaning that there are some steps executed *after* the hash is computed that can change the content of the output file. To get a real hash of the output, you can use `webpack-plugin-hash-output`